# Could not load file or assembly 'businesslogic' or one of its dependencies. Access is denied

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net-assembly

I am getting the above error. I get good build but when i run web application, i get `'Could not load file or assembly 'businesslogic' or one of its dependencies. Access is denied.'`. I have given the `Full Control permission` to Temporary ASP.NET Files in `Framework64` folder. Below are the details about the error. I checked the dll in separate project. It do not have any error. I got good build for the businessLogic project dll. So I don't understand what could be error.

Description: `An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.`

Exception Details: `System.IO.FileLoadException: Could not load file or assembly 'businesslogic' or one of its dependencies. Access is denied.`

Source Error:

```
An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below.

Assembly Load Trace: The following information can be helpful to determine why the assembly 'businesslogic' could not be loaded.


=== Pre-bind state information ===
LOG: DisplayName = businesslogic
 (Partial)
WRN: Partial binding information was supplied for an assembly:
WRN: Assembly Name: businesslogic | Domain ID: 3
WRN: A partial bind occurs when only part of the assembly display name is provided.
WRN: This might result in the binder loading an incorrect assembly.
WRN: It is recommended to provide a fully specified textual identity for the assembly,
WRN: that consists of the simple name, version, culture, and public key token.
WRN: See whitepaper http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=109270 for more information and common solutions to this issue.
LOG: Appbase = file:///C:/Gayatri/VSProjects/Cobalt.Umbraco.Component/Cobalt.Umbraco.Component/
LOG: Initial PrivatePath = C:\Gayatri\VSProjects\Cobalt.Umbraco.Component\Cobalt.Umbraco.Component\bin
Calling assembly : (Unknown).
===
LOG: This bind starts in default load context.
LOG: Using application configuration file: C:\Gayatri\VSProjects\Cobalt.Umbraco.Component\Cobalt.Umbraco.Component\web.config
LOG: Using host configuration file: C:\Users\Gayatri.Rane\Documents\IISExpress\config\aspnet.config
LOG: Using machine configuration file from C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\config\machine.config.
LOG: Policy not being applied to reference at this time (private, custom, partial, or location-based assembly bind).
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Users/Gayatri.Rane/AppData/Local/Temp/Temporary ASP.NET Files/root/65bbe46a/a7dee2d8/businesslogic.DLL.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Users/Gayatri.Rane/AppData/Local/Temp/Temporary ASP.NET Files/root/65bbe46a/a7dee2d8/businesslogic/businesslogic.DLL.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Gayatri/VSProjects/Cobalt.Umbraco.Component/Cobalt.Umbraco.Component/bin/businesslogic.DLL.
LOG: Using application configuration file: C:\Gayatri\VSProjects\Cobalt.Umbraco.Component\Cobalt.Umbraco.Component\web.config
LOG: Using host configuration file: C:\Users\Gayatri.Rane\Documents\IISExpress\config\aspnet.config
LOG: Using machine configuration file from C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\config\machine.config.
LOG: Policy not being applied to reference at this time (private, custom, partial, or location-based assembly bind).
ERR: Failed to complete setup of assembly (hr = 0x80070005). Probing terminated.
```

Stack Trace:

```
[FileLoadException: Could not load file or assembly 'businesslogic' or one of its dependencies. Access is denied.]

[FileLoadException: Could not load file or assembly 'businesslogic, Version=1.0.4392.20885, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' or one of its dependencies. Access is denied.]
   System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly._nLoad(AssemblyName fileName, String codeBase, Evidence assemblySecurity, RuntimeAssembly locationHint, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, IntPtr pPrivHostBinder, Boolean throwOnFileNotFound, Boolean forIntrospection, Boolean suppressSecurityChecks) +0
   System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly.nLoad(AssemblyName fileName, String codeBase, Evidence assemblySecurity, RuntimeAssembly locationHint, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, IntPtr pPrivHostBinder, Boolean throwOnFileNotFound, Boolean forIntrospection, Boolean suppressSecurityChecks) +34
   System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly.InternalLoadAssemblyName(AssemblyName assemblyRef, Evidence assemblySecurity, RuntimeAssembly reqAssembly, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, IntPtr pPrivHostBinder, Boolean throwOnFileNotFound, Boolean forIntrospection, Boolean suppressSecurityChecks) +152
   System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly.InternalLoad(String assemblyString, Evidence assemblySecurity, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, IntPtr pPrivHostBinder, Boolean forIntrospection) +77
   System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly.InternalLoad(String assemblyString, Evidence assemblySecurity, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, Boolean forIntrospection) +16
   System.Reflection.Assembly.Load(String assemblyString) +28
   System.Web.Configuration.CompilationSection.LoadAssemblyHelper(String assemblyName, Boolean starDirective) +38

[ConfigurationErrorsException: Could not load file or assembly 'businesslogic, Version=1.0.4392.20885, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' or one of its dependencies. Access is denied.]
   System.Web.Configuration.CompilationSection.LoadAssemblyHelper(String assemblyName, Boolean starDirective) +752
   System.Web.Configuration.CompilationSection.LoadAllAssembliesFromAppDomainBinDirectory() +218
   System.Web.Configuration.CompilationSection.LoadAssembly(AssemblyInfo ai) +130
   System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.GetReferencedAssemblies(CompilationSection compConfig) +170
   System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.GetPreStartInitMethodsFromReferencedAssemblies() +91
   System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.CallPreStartInitMethods(String preStartInitListPath, Boolean& isRefAssemblyLoaded) +285
   System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.ExecutePreAppStart() +153
   System.Web.Hosting.HostingEnvironment.Initialize(ApplicationManager appManager, IApplicationHost appHost, IConfigMapPathFactory configMapPathFactory, HostingEnvironmentParameters hostingParameters, PolicyLevel policyLevel, Exception appDomainCreationException) +516

[HttpException (0x80004005): Could not load file or assembly 'businesslogic, Version=1.0.4392.20885, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' or one of its dependencies. Access is denied.]
   System.Web.HttpRuntime.FirstRequestInit(HttpContext context) +9913572
   System.Web.HttpRuntime.EnsureFirstRequestInit(HttpContext context) +101
   System.Web.HttpRuntime.ProcessRequestNotificationPrivate(IIS7WorkerRequest wr, HttpContext context) +254
```

Thanks, any suggestion??

Comment: Please make your post more readable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I have given the Full Control permission to Temporary ASP.NET Files in **Framework64** folder.

Yet your exception clearly states the path is not using the Framework64 folder:

> LOG: Using machine configuration file from C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\config\machine.config.

You might want to start there and re-check your permissions.

Comment: Aww.. I see now.. I gave the access and seems problem is solved now. Thank you very much..

Comment: Glad to hear. My pleasure.